# UIWebView ContentSize Height

Tags: ios, webview, uiscrollview, height

I have a `UIImage`, a `UILabel` and a `UIWebView` inside a `UIScrollView`. Basically, I'm calculating the height of both the `UIImage` and the `UILabel` and adding it to the `UIWebView` height to set the UIScrollView's contentSize.

Here's how I calculate the UIWebView height:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:webView.scrollView.contentSize];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, frame.size.height + y + 10);

    [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(x-8, y, webView.frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [webView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}
```

The problem is for some cases the `UIWebView` is cut on the bottom... Any ideia why?

This might be relevant: the `UIWebView` content is HTML code I have no control on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try out the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = WebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    WebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [WebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    WebView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
}
```